# Add proxy setting to Nuget (.NET Core SDK 2.1) at Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: .net, .net-core, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using .NET Core SDK at Ubuntu 14.04, under proxy authorization required network.

I added http_proxy and http_proxy.user configuration to Nuget.Config, by editing via editor, but I can't set http_proxy.password because this password phrase must be encrypted.

I know using nuget.exe and type "nuget config -set" to set http_proxy.password to Nuget.Config, but .NET Core SDK CLI ("dotnet nuget ...") don't have this option.

Is there any way to get encrypted password phrase?
(or using .NET Core SDK CLI to set password)

Or you need to install Mono and nuget.exe?

```
.NET Core SDK (global.json ):
 Version:   2.1.302
 Commit:    9048955601

Runtime
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  14.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.14.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.2
  Commit:  811c3ce6c0

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.302 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NET
```